# To know the version of the code without installing the application at android

Tags: android, android-service, android-install-apk, android-webservice

We have our update server, we have a different apk ([different version](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html) of Android code).
A) The first arc API 11 and above
B) The second apk API 16 and above
How can I find out the version of code on the device **without installing the application**. 
It is necessary to send the user directly to the correct version of the apk in the mail. If the user have on the device  the api 16 and highly, then he needs to send the second apk (B)

Comment: Why not maintain only one instance of code with API level conditions handled?

Comment: Do you send the user to a website? Then perhaps you can tell the version by the user-agent string of the request and then on the website provide the correct APK or a redirect there.